# How to detect app crashes and reopen app in android

Tags: android, file, memory-leaks, crash, out-of-memory

I found that my app will crash and show empty activities when I want to use it from background that I let it in background after few minutes even one day.

I let `super.onCreate(null)` in `onCreate()` when I created all activities of my app. I didn't keep any data by using savedInstanceState.

I tried to use `LifecycleObserver` to detect when app goes to the background and come back to the foreground, and if app in background over 5 minutes, I will let my app open my first activity to login app again.It didn't enter onResume and crash.

But when I use my app again from background after 10 minutes, it didn't open first activity, but still crash and show empty activities, and these empty activities could't work.

Here is my `LifecycleObserver` code:

```
public class HomePageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LifecycleObserver {

    ...

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(null);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);

        ....
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    public void appInResumeState() {
        if(recordBgDate.length() != 0 && recordBgTime.length() != 0){
            if(recordBgDate.compareTo(MyUtility.getSystemDate()) == 0){
                if(MyUtility.getMinWhenAppInBackground(recordBgTime) < 5){
                    recordBgDate = "";
                    recordBgTime = "";
                    return;
                }else{
                    recordBgDate = "";
                    recordBgTime = "";
                    jumpToSpecificActivityAndFinish(CoverActivity.class);
                }
            }else{
                recordBgDate = "";
                recordBgTime = "";
                jumpToSpecificActivityAndFinish(CoverActivity.class);
            }
        }
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
    public void appInPauseState() {
        recordBgDate = MyUtility.getSystemDate(); // yyyyMMdd.
        recordBgTime = MyUtility.getSystemDateAndTime(); // yyyyMMddHHmmss.
    }

}
```

Here are I get the system time function and count the time:

```
public static final String getSystemDateAndTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+8"));
    Date curDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String time = formatter.format(curDate);
    return time;
}

public static final String getSystemDate() {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+8"));
    Date curDate = new Date();
    String time = formatter.format(curDate);
    return time;
}

public static final Integer getMinWhenAppInBackground(String _backgroundTime){
    String nowTime = getSystemDateAndTime();
    return (Integer.valueOf(nowTime.substring(8, 10)) - Integer.valueOf(_backgroundTime.substring(8, 10))) * 60 + (Integer.valueOf(nowTime.substring(10, 12)) - Integer.valueOf(_backgroundTime.substring(10, 12)));
}
```

I don't really know how to fix it, it has any way to detect my app is crash or even OOM, and I can reopen it, thank you!

Here is my log that my app crashes after I want to use it and it in background after few minutes.

```
--------- beginning of crash
12-24 16:04:03.968 E/AndroidRuntime(14610): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-24 16:04:03.968 E/AndroidRuntime(14610): Process: com.gmpsykr.each, PID: 14610
12-24 16:04:03.968 E/AndroidRuntime(14610): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1001, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.gmpsykr.each/com.gmpsykr.each.Post.PostActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a null object reference
12-24 16:04:03.968 E/AndroidRuntime(14610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4297)
12-24 16:04:03.968 E/AndroidRuntime(14610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4347)
12-24 16:04:03.968 E/AndroidRuntime(14610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
12-24 16:04:03.968 E/AndroidRuntime(14610):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1557)
12-24 16:04:03.968 E/AndroidRuntime(14610):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-24 16:04:03.968 E/AndroidRuntime(14610):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
12-24 16:04:03.968 E/AndroidRuntime(14610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6459)
12-24 16:04:03.968 E/AndroidRuntime(14610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-24 16:04:03.968 E/AndroidRuntime(14610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938)
12-24 16:04:03.968 E/AndroidRuntime(14610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
12-24 16:04:03.968 E/AndroidRuntime(14610): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a null object reference
12-24 16:04:03.968 E/AndroidRuntime(14610):     at com.gmpsykr.each.Post.PostActivity.onActivityResult(PostActivity.java:416)
12-24 16:04:03.968 E/AndroidRuntime(14610):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6926)
12-24 16:04:03.968 E/AndroidRuntime(14610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4293)
12-24 16:04:03.968 E/AndroidRuntime(14610):     ... 9 more
--------- beginning of system
12-26 09:48:11.926 E/BatSS   ( 2413): no controller energy info supplied
12-26 09:48:11.932 E/BatSS   ( 2413): no controller energy info supplied
12-26 09:48:24.217 E/BatSS   ( 2413): no controller energy info supplied
12-26 09:48:24.446 E/ConnectivityService( 2413): Exception in removeRoute: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '5455 network route remove 111 wlan0 fe80::/64' failed with '400 5455 removeRoute() failed (No such device)'
12-26 09:48:24.448 E/ConnectivityService( 2413): Exception in removeRoute: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '5456 network route remove 111 wlan0 172.16.16.0/24' failed with '400 5456 removeRoute() failed (No such device)'
12-26 09:48:24.451 E/ConnectivityService( 2413): Exception in removeRoute: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '5457 network route remove 111 wlan0 0.0.0.0/0 172.16.16.1' failed with '400 5457 removeRoute() failed (No such device)'
12-26 09:48:24.462 E/Nat464Xlat( 2413): startClat: Can't start clat on null interface
12-26 09:48:24.487 E/Nat464Xlat( 2413): startClat: Can't start clat on null interface
12-26 09:48:34.883 E/BatSS   ( 2413): no controller energy info supplied
12-26 09:48:34.893 E/BatSS   ( 2413): no controller energy info supplied
--------- beginning of main
12-26 09:48:36.628 E/CompactDiskManagerImpl.cpp(16818): Failed to remove new folder structure directories: No such file or directory
12-26 09:48:37.042 E/MDH     (10354): [Auth] Failed to get token with scope [oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/mdh https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webhistory]
12-26 09:48:37.640 E/MDH     (10354): [Auth] Failed to get token with scope [oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/mdh https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webhistory]
12-26 09:48:37.644 E/MDH     (10354): [Footprints] Sync execution exception
12-26 09:48:37.649 E/MDH     (10354): [Footprints] Sync execution exception
12-26 09:48:39.055 E/art     (16818): No implementation found for int com.facebook.soloader.MergedSoMapping$Invoke_JNI_OnLoad.libmobileconfigonomnistore_jni_so() (tried Java_com_facebook_soloader_MergedSoMapping_00024Invoke_1JNI_1OnLoad_libmobileconfigonomnistore_1jni_1so and Java_com_facebook_soloader_MergedSoMapping_00024Invoke_1JNI_1OnLoad_libmobileconfigonomnistore_1jni_1so__)
12-26 09:48:39.283 E/WifiHAL ( 2413): handleResponse: QCA_WLAN_VENDOR_ATTR_LL_STATS_NUM_RADIOS not found
12-26 09:48:39.283 E/WifiHAL ( 2413): nl80211: requestResponse->nl_recvmsgs failed: -5
12-26 09:48:39.757 E/MDH     (10354): [Auth] Failed to get token with scope [oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/mdh https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webhistory]
12-26 09:48:40.695 E/MDH     (10354): [Auth] Failed to get token with scope [oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/mdh https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webhistory]
12-26 09:48:40.700 E/MDH     (10354): [Footprints] Sync execution exception
12-26 09:48:40.704 E/MDH     (10354): [Footprints] Sync execution exception
12-26 09:48:41.517 E/dalvik-internals(16818): skipping IsUpToDate check for incoming dex file
12-26 09:48:41.519 E/dalvik-internals(16818): skipping IsUpToDate check for incoming dex file
12-26 09:48:41.519 E/dalvik-internals(16818): skipping HasCollisions check for incoming dex file
12-26 09:48:41.519 E/dalvik-internals(16818): skipping IsUpToDate check for incoming dex file
12-26 09:48:41.520 E/dalvik-internals(16818): skipping IsUpToDate check for incoming dex file
12-26 09:48:41.520 E/dalvik-internals(16818): skipping HasCollisions check for incoming dex file
12-26 09:48:41.521 E/dalvik-internals(16818): skipping IsUpToDate check for incoming dex file
12-26 09:48:41.523 E/dalvik-internals(16818): skipping IsUpToDate check for incoming dex file
12-26 09:48:41.523 E/dalvik-internals(16818): skipping HasCollisions check for incoming dex file
12-26 09:48:42.075 E/fb4a.ActivityRecognition(16818): ActivityRecognition Permission is missing
12-26 09:48:42.075 E/fb4a.ActivityRecognition(16818): java.lang.SecurityException: Activity detection usage requires the ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION permission
12-26 09:48:42.075 E/fb4a.ActivityRecognition(16818):   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1692)
12-26 09:48:42.075 E/fb4a.ActivityRecognition(16818):   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1645)
12-26 09:48:42.075 E/fb4a.ActivityRecognition(16818):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.location.zza.A01()
12-26 09:48:42.075 E/fb4a.ActivityRecognition(16818):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.location.zzap.DQy()
12-26 09:48:42.075 E/fb4a.ActivityRecognition(16818):   at X.47F.A0F()
12-26 09:48:42.075 E/fb4a.ActivityRecognition(16818):   at X.47F.A0G(:5)
12-26 09:48:42.075 E/fb4a.ActivityRecognition(16818):   at X.476.Aj9(:71)
12-26 09:48:42.075 E/fb4a.ActivityRecognition(16818):   at X.44a.Aj9(:5)
12-26 09:48:42.075 E/fb4a.ActivityRecognition(16818):   at X.44K.A0A(:135)
12-26 09:48:42.075 E/fb4a.ActivityRecognition(16818):   at X.5Lx.Ctx()
12-26 09:48:42.075 E/fb4a.ActivityRecognition(16818):   at X.5Lw.run(:93)
12-26 09:48:42.075 E/fb4a.ActivityRecognition(16818):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
12-26 09:48:42.075 E/fb4a.ActivityRecognition(16818):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-26 09:48:42.075 E/fb4a.ActivityRecognition(16818):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
12-26 09:48:42.075 E/fb4a.ActivityRecognition(16818):   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
12-26 09:48:42.075 E/fb4a.ActivityRecognition(16818):   at X.1o5.run(:0)
12-26 09:48:42.308 E/WifiHAL ( 2413): handleResponse: QCA_WLAN_VENDOR_ATTR_LL_STATS_NUM_RADIOS not found
12-26 09:48:42.308 E/WifiHAL ( 2413): nl80211: requestResponse->nl_recvmsgs failed: -5
12-26 09:48:42.334 E/ACRA    (16937): Initializing ANR detector for process: com.facebook.appmanager
12-26 09:48:42.398 E/SQLiteLog(16937): (14) cannot open file at line 32456 of [bda77dda96]
12-26 09:48:42.398 E/SQLiteLog(16937): (14) os_unix.c:32456: (2) open(/data/user/0/com.facebook.appmanager/databases/androidx.work.workdb) - 
12-26 09:48:42.398 E/SQLiteConnection(16937): DB info: sqlite3_open_v2, path: /data/user/0/com.facebook.appmanager/databases/androidx.work.workdb, flag: 2, ret: 14
12-26 09:48:42.398 E/SQLiteConnection(16937): DB info: errno = 2, errno message = No such file or directory
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937): Failed to open database '/data/user/0/com.facebook.appmanager/databases/androidx.work.workdb'.
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:239)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:223)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:468)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:190)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:182)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:878)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:858)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:756)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:731)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at com.facebook.oxygen.common.androidx.workmanager.initializer.b.a(WorkManagerDatabase.java:20)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at com.facebook.oxygen.appmanager.app.c.b(AppManagerApplicationImpl.java:19)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at com.facebook.oxygen.common.e.b.d.onCreate(OxpDelegatingApplication.java:68)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1037)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5662)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1573)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6459)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938)
12-26 09:48:42.402 E/SQLiteDatabase(16937):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
12-26 09:48:42.722 E/ActivityThread(16937): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.appmanager.nekodirect
12-26 09:48:43.164 E/MDH     (10354): [Auth] Failed to get token with scope [oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/mdh https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webhistory]
12-26 09:48:43.627 E/MDH     (10354): [Auth] Failed to get token with scope [oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/mdh https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webhistory]
12-26 09:48:43.638 E/MDH     (10354): [Footprints] Sync execution exception
12-26 09:48:43.644 E/MDH     (10354): [Footprints] Sync execution exception
12-26 09:48:45.347 E/WifiHAL ( 2413): handleResponse: QCA_WLAN_VENDOR_ATTR_LL_STATS_NUM_RADIOS not found
12-26 09:48:45.347 E/WifiHAL ( 2413): nl80211: requestResponse->nl_recvmsgs failed: -5
12-26 09:48:48.395 E/WifiHAL ( 2413): handleResponse: QCA_WLAN_VENDOR_ATTR_LL_STATS_NUM_RADIOS not found
12-26 09:48:48.395 E/WifiHAL ( 2413): nl80211: requestResponse->nl_recvmsgs failed: -5
12-26 09:48:49.264 E/MDH     (10354): [Auth] Failed to get token with scope [oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/mdh https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webhistory]
12-26 09:48:49.705 E/MDH     (10354): [Auth] Failed to get token with scope [oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/mdh https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webhistory]
12-26 09:48:49.708 E/MDH     (10354): [Footprints] Sync execution exception
12-26 09:48:49.712 E/MDH     (10354): [Footprints] Sync execution exception
12-26 09:48:50.792 E/WakeLock( 2886): GCM_CONN_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
12-26 09:48:51.331 E/MDH     (10354): [Auth] Failed to get token with scope [oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/mdh https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webhistory]
12-26 09:48:51.430 E/WifiHAL ( 2413): handleResponse: QCA_WLAN_VENDOR_ATTR_LL_STATS_NUM_RADIOS not found
12-26 09:48:51.430 E/WifiHAL ( 2413): nl80211: requestResponse->nl_recvmsgs failed: -5
12-26 09:48:51.897 E/MDH     (10354): [Auth] Failed to get token with scope [oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/mdh https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webhistory]
12-26 09:48:51.901 E/MDH     (10354): [Footprints] Sync execution exception
12-26 09:48:51.905 E/MDH     (10354): [Footprints] Sync execution exception
12-26 09:48:53.791 E/WifiHAL ( 2413): handleResponse: QCA_WLAN_VENDOR_ATTR_LL_STATS_NUM_RADIOS not found
12-26 09:48:53.791 E/WifiHAL ( 2413): nl80211: requestResponse->nl_recvmsgs failed: -5
12-26 09:48:53.794 E/BatSS   ( 2413): no controller energy info supplied
12-26 09:48:53.800 E/BatSS   ( 2413): no controller energy info supplied
12-26 09:48:54.162 E/SmartNS_Utility(14446): read /sys/class/dual_role_usb/otg_default/data_role failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/dual_role_usb/otg_default/data_role (No such file or directory)
...
```

**Base on the log, I have some new question:**

In my app I need to create folder to put some images, the log show that there is something wrong when I create folder.

Maybe I didn't close the `File` when the folder is exist, but I don't know how to close it. Can anyone tell me how to fix that, thank you!

Here is my code:

```
File storageDir = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(), "myFolder");      
createAppFolder(storageDir);


 public static final void createAppFolder(File _storageDir) {
        if (!_storageDir.exists()) {
            boolean rv = _storageDir.mkdir();
            Log.e("TAG", "state: " + (rv ? "success" : "fail"));
        } else {
            Log.e("TAG", "folder exist");
        }
    }
```

Comment: why 'super.onCreate(null);'

Comment: @PankajKumar because when I use savedInstanceState, it will be crash but not show empty activities, I don't want my app crash directly.

Comment: Surely the better approach would be to fix your memory handling error?

Comment: @KenY-N you mean I need to use savedInstanceStat, and find why my app OOM?

Comment: @KenY-N I try to detect my memory when app in background, it looks not using more memory when it in background.

Comment: Your LogCat shows you have a null `File` object; perhaps your code is forgetting to close a file thus runs out of file handles?

Comment: @KenY-N I will try to fix that, thank you! And I want to ask did I should to keep use LifecycleObserver to detect my app and let login again.